# NSIS : Inserting links in label

Tags: nsis

Suppose I have following nsDialog label:

> By clicking Accept I agree to the Example's License Agreement and Privacy Policy. You may access features that requires use of personal information. For more information, please download Example's Content Policy.

I want to insert the links in this label like below:

> By clicking Accept I agree to the Example's [License Agreement](http://www.example.com) and [Privacy Policy](http://www.example.com). You may access features that requires use of personal information. For more information, please download Example's [Content Policy](http://www.example.com).*

I am able to create links with `NSD_CreateLink` but I dont know how to make it as above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create several labels with ${NSD_CreateLabel} like this ( '|' is separator ):

```
              Label1             |    Label2     |Label3| Label4  |  Label5...
```

By clicking Accept I agree to the Example's | License Agreement | and | Privacy Policy | You may access...

So your text will be composed from several separate labels placed one by one to create your text.

Then simply use Linker plug-in (http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Linker_plug-in - few days ago I updated it to support transparent texts) with those labels which should be links:

```
Linker::link /NOUNLOAD $Label2Hwnd "http://www.unsigned-softworks.sk/"
Linker::link /NOUNLOAD $Label4Hwnd "http://www.graphical-installer.com/"
```

Comment: Thanks.. I think its the best way to work around this problem so far.

Comment: i dont know what i am doing wrong but the link does not show up, the code is : `${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 75u 100% 10u "License Agreement"
 Pop $label3
  ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 85u 100% 10u "Privacy Policy"
 Pop $label4
  Linker::link /NOUNLOAD $label3 "http://www.unsigned-softworks.sk/"
  Linker::link /NOUNLOAD $label4 "http://www.graphical-installer.com/"`

Comment: Do not forget that Linker plug-in does NOT executes the link (clicked text). You need to do that manually in function. Add onClick function for your control e.g. GetFunctionAddress $0 MoreDetailsClick
 nsDialogs::OnClick $Labe $0

Comment: Hi @Slappy , could you kindly update the answer with an example of how to use `${NSD_CreateLabel}` with pipes? I have tried several mathods and failed, and couldn't find further information about the topic. Thanks from ahead!

Comment: There are no Pipes! | in text mark end of one label and start of another one.

Answer (score 2):

There is no perfect solution to this other than writing your own plugin that hosts IE or something like that.

A RichEdit textbox is supposed to support links like that but I never got it working 100%, you might try to play with the RTF data some more.

If your target is XP+ you can use the SysLink control. If you search the NSIS forum you will see that there are some issues with it and SetCtlColors but it seems to work fine in a nsDialogs page on Win7.

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!define /math EM_SETBKGNDCOLOR ${WM_USER} + 67
!define /math EM_GETTEXTRANGE ${WM_USER} + 75
!define /math EM_AUTOURLDETECT ${WM_USER} + 91
!define /math EM_SETTEXTEX ${WM_USER} + 97
!define EM_SETEVENTMASK 0x0445
!define ES_NOOLEDRAGDROP 8
!define ENM_LINK 0x4000000
!define EN_LINK 0x70B
!define NM_CLICK -2
!define NM_RETURN -4

XPStyle On ; Required by syslink (ComCtl v6)
Page Custom mypage mypageleave

var syslink

Function mypage
nsDialogs::Create 1018
pop $0

nsDialogs::CreateControl RichEdit20A ${WS_VISIBLE}|${WS_CHILD}|${WS_TABSTOP}|${ES_READONLY}|${ES_NOOLEDRAGDROP} ${WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY} 10u 10u 80% 10u ''
pop $0
System::Call user32::GetSysColor(i15)i.r1
SendMessage $0 ${EM_SETBKGNDCOLOR} 0 $1
SendMessage $0 ${EM_AUTOURLDETECT} 1 0
SendMessage $0 ${EM_SETEVENTMASK} 0 ${ENM_LINK}
System::Call *(i0,i0)i.r1
;//blogs.msdn.com/b/murrays/archive/2009/09/24/richedit-friendly-name-hyperlinks.aspx# but could not get it to fully work?
SendMessage $0 ${EM_SETTEXTEX} $1 'STR:{\rtf1{\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK "http://example.org"}}{\fldresult{Richedit}}} says hello}'
System::Free $1
${NSD_OnNotify} $0 onrichclick

nsDialogs::CreateControl SysLink ${WS_CHILD}|${WS_VISIBLE}|${WS_TABSTOP} 0 10u 30u -20u 10u `Hello from <A>SysLink</A>...`
pop $syslink
${NSD_OnNotify} $syslink onsyslinkclick

nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function mypageleave
System::Call 'user32::DestroyWindow(i $syslink)'
FunctionEnd

Function onrichclick
Pop $0
Pop $1
Pop $2
${If} $1 = ${EN_LINK}
    System::Call "*$2(i,i,i,i.r1,i,i,i.r2,i.r3)"
    ${If} $3 >= 0 ; Is it a CHARRANGE we can work with?
        ${If} $1 = ${WM_LBUTTONDOWN}
            IntOp $1 $3 - $2 ; length
            IntOp $1 $1 + 1 ; \0
            System::Call '*(ir2,ir3,i,i,&t$1)i.r1' ; TEXTRANGE + align + string
            IntOp $2 $1 + 16
            System::Call '*$1(i,i,ir2)'
            SendMessage $0 ${EM_GETTEXTRANGE} 0 $1
            System::Call "*$2(&t999.r2)"
            ExecShell open $2
            System::Free $1
        ${EndIf}
    ${EndIf}
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Function onsyslinkclick
Pop $0
Pop $1
Pop $2
${If} $0 = $syslink
    ${If} $1 = ${NM_CLICK}
    ${OrIf} $1 = ${NM_RETURN}
        System::Call `*$2(i,i,i,i,i.r3)`
        ${If} $3 == 0 ; link index
            ; This could probably be changed to extract the link from <A href="foo">...</A> in the syslink
            ExecShell open `http://example.com/`
        ${EndIf}
    ${EndIf}
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks..but I need something that works for lower window versions as well. I think Slappy's answer is much useful. Though its simply a work-around but its reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up:

Using this GetTextExtent: https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Get_text_dimensions
and a call to: GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXMENUCHECK)

and a few small vertical/horizontal pixel fixing.

```
!define FIRST_PART "I have read and accepted the "

...

; Get the dialog's default font in $R1

SendMessage $DIALOG ${WM_GETFONT} 0 0 $R1

; Get width for text into $R2
${GetTextExtent} $R1 "${FIRST_PART}" $R2 $R3

; Get checkbox width into $0

System::Call 'user32::GetSystemMetrics(i 71) i .r0' ;SM_CXMENUCHECK = 71

IntOp $1 $R2 + $0 ; width of checkbox + text into $1
IntOp $1 $1 - 2 ; -2 fixes some checkbox extra padding

; $1 contains the required width ($R3 the line height)

${NSD_CreateCheckbox} ${TEXT_LEFT_START_POS}u ${CHECKBOX_TOP}u $1u $R3u ${FIRST_PART}


; And now, the next label or link can be positioned by:

IntOp $1 ${TEXT_LEFT_START_POS} + $1 ; position after checkbox and text
```