# Implement a Hyperlink into an LangString

Tags: nsis

Actually im Trying with NSIS standard-libary to implement a Hyperlink into my LangString. But when I "only" write the Link into the LangString it dont get clickable.

I´m using an own .nsh do Build the LangStrings:

```
!undef LANG
!define LANG = "English"
!LANG_STRING "myTest" "search on google: https://google.com/"
```

In my nsis Main the Code-Snippet looks like:

```
!macro LANG_STRING NAME VALUE
  LangString "${NAME}" "${LANG_${LANG}}" "${VALUE}"
!macroend
!macro LANG_LOAD lang
  !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "${lang}"
  !verbose 1
  !include "descriptions\${lang}.nsh"
  !verbose 4
  !undef LANG
!macroend
#Pages(here i build my pages up)
!insertmacro LANG_LOAD "English"
```

Is there a handling that i can make it possible and when yes where i must implement it.

Comment: Which page? A custom page or a built-in page?

Comment: An built in Page, mainly the Component Page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in support for this. NSIS does not try to detect URLs in strings and Windows controls are rather limited in older versions (before XP).

You can fake it with a RichEdit control but there is no built in WM_NOTIFY handler to launch the URL:

```
System::Call 'KERNEL32::LoadLibrary(t "MsftEdit")' ; 4.1+, Windows XP SP1 and later
FindWindow $9 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
SendMessage $9 ${WM_GETFONT} 0 0 $8
System::Call 'USER32::CreateWindowExW(i ${WS_EX_TRANSPARENT}, w "RICHEDIT50W", p0, i ${DEFAULT_STYLES}|${WS_TABSTOP}|${ES_MULTILINE}|${ES_READONLY}, i 0, i 0, i 300, i 50, p $9, p 0, p 0, p 0)p.s'
Pop $9
SendMessage $9 ${WM_SETFONT} $8 1
!define /math EM_SETTEXTEX ${WM_USER} + 97
System::Call "USER32::SendMessage(p$9,i${EM_SETTEXTEX},*l0,ts)" '{\rtf1{Hello} {\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nsis"}}{\fldrslt{SO link}}} {World}}'
```

It is possible to handle WM_NOTIFY on a nsDialogs page. On built-in pages you need a custom plug-in. You could perhaps ask the author of the [ButtonEvent plug-in](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/ButtonEvent_plug-in) to add support for this message. If < XP SP1 support is needed you would have to use a older version of the RichEdit control and the EM_AUTOURLDETECT message instead, this means the URL must be visible in the text. The [nsDialogs example](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Examples/nsDialogs/example.nsi) in NSIS v3 does this.

Another alternative is the [SysLink control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/syslink-overview) but it suffers from the same WM_NOTIFY issue and is also limited to Windows XP and later, ComCtlv6 (`XPStyle On`) and is Unicode only. A different internal implementation exists on Windows 2000 but I'm not sure if it is documented.

The final alternative is the [Linker plug-in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18246591). I have never tried it myself and you must create several labels if you want to mix links and normal text.